# Word request: Mensatüte

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests, culture, history

I would like to know the Chinese translation of the German word "Mensatüte".

**Explanation:**

German people who a bit older will remember the so-called ["Wundertüte"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wundert%C3%BCte?wprov=sfla1) from their childhood. This is a paper bag for children filled with sweets and other surprises, like little gadgets.

In 2013, the Heinrich-Heine University of Düsseldorf was distributing so-called "Mensatüten" to their students for free at the university restaurant.

Here, the word "Mensa" means university restaurant (French: "resto u" in a colloquial way) and could be translated to Chinese by 食堂 according to my experience, although a 食堂 is a canteen not limited to the setting of university but can be your employer's canteen more general as well. If you would like to choose another word for "Mensa" or to be more explicitly by saying 大学食堂, feel free to do so.

Now, a "Mensatüte" is similar to the former "Wundertüte" a paper bag distributed at the "Mensa" to students instead of small childrens and filled with more mature surprises like little snacks.

I remember there were chips and little cans of drinks in it, and maybe a chocolate bar.

**Preliminary thoughts on a possible translation:**

If I were to translate this, I would say 大学食堂红包, but I'm not sure if this is comprehensible in the intended way as the "Mensatüte" is neither an envelope nor does it contain money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wundertüte: 盲盒

Wundertüte: is a "Wonder bag" because you don't know exactly what is in there: one wonders, man wundert sich, plus the word play of "a wonder, something marvellous" "ein Wunder, etwas Besonderes"

Wundertüte: 奇迹袋子
盲盒: blind box (not sure exactly *what* is in there.)

Latin: mensa: table, meal, sacrificial table

German: die Mensa: student canteen

Mensatüte: (大学)食堂盲盒

> 盲盒，是指消费者不能提前得知具体产品款式的玩具盒子，具有随机属性。这种诞生于日本的潮玩，最初名字叫mini
> figures，流行欧美后也开始被称作blind
> box。盲盒作为一种潮流玩具，盲盒精准切入年轻消费者市场，众多如考古盲盒、文具盲盒、美妆盲盒、零食盲盒等“盲盒+”商业模式也迅速产生。

Comment: Now, I don't know which answer to accept. I like your translation a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

may be “食堂福袋”

“食堂”, you already know th meaning

[“福袋”](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A6%8F%E8%A2%8B#:%7E:text=%E7%A6%8F%E8%A2%8B%EF%BC%88%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8F%E3%81%B6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8D%EF%BC%89%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF,%E3%81%A8%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B6%E5%BA%97%E8%88%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%EF%BC%89%E3%80%82) is a bag of merchandises, provided by a department stores, shops; normally, the total value is more the price one paid for, such as

$100, one would get $110-120 goods

this practice is quite popular in japan, taiwan & hong kong

for customers, they get more goods, for the same price; for the shops, they can “send away” any unwanted stocks

have fun :)